# Using a transistor as a switch

Tags: transistors, avr, atmega, breadboard

I am attaching a motor to an ATmega32 chip. I want to build an H-bridge but before doing that, I want to control the motor using the chip. I bought few NPN Transistors from RadioShack. I have 5V running though the breadboard. I attached Vcc to the Collector, Base to the Pin, and Emitter to the motor. And other wire of motor is hooked up to Ground. Unfortunately, the power coming out of the transistor is too low, the motor is barely moving (As opposed to when I hook up my motor straight to 5V). What is wrong? Do I need a different transistor or is my setup wrong? If it is the transistor, can you please recommend the right one, I am not too good at those.

Comment: What are the specifications of the motor? Also, the transistor would have an upper limit for the collector current in the specifications sheet. With what you describe, without any current limiting, the transistor might be damaged.

Comment: Precisely. Without any more information you will get no specific answer.

Comment: @Sam_Please give us some more information about the motor and also do you mean that you are connecting the base of the transistor to the output pin of the uC?
I would suggest you to use Mosfet rather than using transistor. If transistor is not fully turned ON, it can dissipate a large amount of heat where as Mosfet are either ON or OFF and have very low on resistance which dissipates little amount of heat.

Comment: Emitter attached to Motor...? Connect MOtor from collector to 5V. Refer these http://www.mcmanis.com/chuck/robotics/tutorial/h-bridge/bjt-circuit.html.....2.http://embedded-lab.com/blog/?p=1159

Comment: the emitter connected to the motor is no big deal if base voltage can rise enough to fully turn on the bjt (that probably is the problem here). if he'd done the "canonical" common emitter circuit he'd burn his transistors.

Comment: For future reference.  Please don't cross-post.  [StackExchange policy is against cross-posting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu). You can make a flag to the moderators and they will migrate your question, if you so choose.

Comment: What voltage and current is the motor rated for?  How much does it draw when you connect it directly to the 5 V supply?  What is the actual voltage of the 5 V supply when the motor is connected to it?

Answer (score 1):

As already noted, the direct connection of a NPN BJT (or N-channel Mosfet) in high-side configuration is not suitable (emitter follower no saturates with equal voltages Vb and Vc). A proper driver is required. For example these ones on figure below (B, instead uses a PNP):

(A) Input Low -> load On; Input High -> Load Off

(B) Input Low -> load Off; Input High -> Load On

The problem with (A) is the initial state under power-on or reset by watchdog activation. Maybe, in some application, can be a bonus.

[image: NPN High side]

Answer (score 0):

With the connections you described, the motor will see only about 4v because of the vbe diode drop; maybe that's the problem? The usual way to do this (base THROUGH RESISTOR to pin, collector to motor and emitter to ground, so motor between vcc and collector) is better since the vce saturation voltage is much lower; the transistor will also dissipate less heat.

Choose the resistor high enough to not fry your mcu pin (40mA max for atmega328 iirc), but low enough to turn the transistor fully on - that is, the current to base must be more than collector current / hfe. One tenth of the motor current would be probably plenty; check the transistor datasheet.

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration is wrong. In a nutshell with an NPN transistor you need to connect one lead of the motor to Vcc and the other on the collector. Then the emitter goes to the ground and the gate to an arduino pin. When the signal on the Arduino pin is high, the transistor will let a significant current pass from its collector to its emitter, thus also through the motor, turning it on. Then there are other issues to consider depending on the transistor you're using and for protecting the micro. I suggest to read this nice article for more specific instructions http://bildr.org/2012/03/rfp30n06le-arduino/

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems.  First, you connected the transistor in the emitter follower configuration instead of common emitter.  That means the available drive voltage is reduced by the 750 mV or so base-emitter drop.  Second, your transistor may not have enough gain.  You didn't say how much current the digital output can deliver, and how much the motor requires to spin well.

Try this:

[image]

This assumes the digital output can deliver 10 mA.  This will allow most small transistors to support a motor current up to a few 100 mA.  If your motor needs more than that, then this simple circuit won't work.  However, without real specs it's pointless to go into more detail.

Also make sure your 5 V supply can really support the motor.  You say it spins well when conntected to the 5 V supply directly.  Measure its voltage to make sure you still have 5 V when the motor is connected.  If not, there is no guarantee what the processor might do.